# compare shared_ptr object equality

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there an standard predicate to compare shared_ptr managed objects for equality.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool target_equal(const T& lhs, const U& rhs)
{
    if(lhs && rhs)
    {
        return *lhs == *rhs;
    }
    else
    {
        return !lhs && !rhs;
    }
}
```

I want something similar to the above code, but will avoid defining it my self if there is already a standard solution.

Comment: is there a need since you can deference them?

Comment: @101010: The `if`  statement is there because apparently you might not be able to dereference them.

Comment: But I need to deal with nulptr when dereferencing them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't such a predicate. An alternative is to use lambda function - but you still need to define it yourself.

Answer (score 12):

No, there isn't a standard solution. The equality operator of shared_ptr and the like compares only the pointers not the managed objects.
Your solution is fine. I propose this version that checks if the pointed object is the same and returns false if one of the shared pointers is null and the other one it is not:

```
template<class T, class U>
bool compare_shared_ptr(const std::shared_ptr<T>&a,const std::shared_ptr<U>&b)
{
  if(a == b) return true;
  if(a && b) return *a == *b;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This returns `false` when one pointer is null, whereas OP's version returns `true`.

Comment: Indeed. I could argue that it makes more sense to return false when one shared pointer is null and the other one it is not, but again OP's version it is different. Edited the answer to reflect that.